# Constructing a Beta Neutral Hedge in a Pairs Strategy

Tags: pairs-trading, optimal-hedge-ratio

Looking for resources / explanation.

Creating a dollar neutral hedge is easy - stockprice-a/stockprice-b

How do I create a beta neutral hedge?

I find discussions but no explicit derivation methods.

Could someone explain or refer me to a resource?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is similar to Dollar Neutral, but instead of balancing the Dollars of the two positions you balance the (dollars * beta) of the two positions. (For example long 50000 USD in a stock with beta of two versus short 100000 USD in a stock with beta of one. 50000*2 = 100000*1 so it is balanced).

Comment: I understand your construction.  Could you explain a bit more why this works?

Comment: Imagine that "the market" is up say 1% tomorrow, then the first stock price is up 2% and the position makes a P&L of 1000 USD, the second stock price is up 1% and the short position makes a loss of 1000 USD. The dollar gains and losses offset each other, which is the definition of a hedge.